# (K)Ubuntu 18.04 boots into emergency mode after Windows 10 was reinstalled

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

So I'm pretty new to Linux and at a loss here. The solutions listed by google and on here didn't help me at all.

I had a working dualboot setup on my ssd which was splitted in a linux partition and a windows partition. After my Windows 10 bluescreen'd on boot I reinstalled it on the same partition as before and followed the instruction on ubuntu-wiki to repair the damaged bootmenu using boot-repair.

GRUB is now working as intended but whenever I try to boot up Kubuntu I end up in emergency mode.

What I already did:

- Disabled fast boot in Windows 10
- Reran boot-repair
- e2fsck on the linux partition via GParted
- Ubuntu recovery mode filesystem check

When I mounted my linux partition form the live cd and took a look at the fstab file I found this:

[image: fstab of linux partition]

What surprised me are the labels of the SSD & HDDs

- My ssd is labeled as /dev/nvme0n1p
- my hdd is labeled as /dev/sda
- my external hdd is labeles as /dev/sdb

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I got the system to boot again after I commented every partition line except the ubuntu partition. Have to see if there remain any problem but at least I can backup my data now.

Comment: @Fabby As stated in my question I tried boot-repair two times and it didn't help at all.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that bit (Was reviewing queues).  **+1** still stands though!  **0:-)** Thank you for sharing, *original comment deleted.*